# NSDate always show the same date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I've been struggling this for hours. I'm trying to find the difference month between two dates.
The start date is correct with system date but the endDate, always show the same date `2014-01-04 00:00:00` regardless what the user input. (and the valuetosave is the date that user input and i save it in userdefaults, and is correct if i see it in log for example the string is `31/12/2014`). So currently I always get 7 for months event the date that user pick is, for example 31 Dec 2014.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:valuetosave];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]

                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

unsigned int unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate  toDate:endDate options:0];
float months = [comps month]+1;
```

Comment: If you read your question, can you understand it?  I couldn't.

Comment: Yeah tell exactly what you want and what you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
```

months got just by changing the dateFormat is `19`.

Comment: @Anudpas...you save my life man...and also sorry for the question that not complete, this think is killing me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Formatter for year

```
YYYY - wrong
yyyy - right
```

Change it your code works fine

More details on [formatting](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)